# Failed prop type: The prop `auth` is marked as required in `Navbar`, but its value is `undefined`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, frontend, react-proptypes

I'm using useSelector instead of mapStateToProps function in my functional component called NavBar.js.
When I run the program, I see this error in the console:

"Failed prop type: The prop `auth` is marked as required in `Navbar`, but its value is `undefined`."

How should I solve it?

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect, shallowEqual, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { logoutUser } from '../../actions/authActions';
import { clearCurrentProfile } from '../../actions/profileActions';

 const Navbar = (props) => {

 const selectedData = useSelector((state) => state, shallowEqual)
 const { isAuthenticated, user } = selectedData.auth;

 return(
   //Code......
 )

}

Navbar.propTypes = {
logoutUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
clearCurrentProfile: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};


export default  withRouter(connect(null, { logoutUser, clearCurrentProfile })(Navbar));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are no longer mapping the state to props but your component is still expecting the prop. To solve this problem, you need to remove `auth` from `propTypes`.

```
Navbar.propTypes = {
  logoutUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  clearCurrentProfile: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired // this is the problem
};
```

Another unrelated issue I am seeing is you're using `connect` to map the action creators to props. I'd suggest removing the use of `connect` entirely by using `useDispatch()` to dispatch your actions. [Learn more](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#usedispatch)

Answer (score 0):

auth is not imported or declared in function
and is also not exported.
it appears only in PropTypes definition.
this might be the problem?